# How do some symbols suddenly have no data?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

Specifically, I'm looking at `INVN` and it has no data. But there are somehow news events about it. I've noticed this has happened before a few times with different symbols. How can there be no data / trades yet there's news from analysts?

[image]

Comment: Well, according to [this page](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/tdk-completes-acquisition-invensense-143000271.html) they were acquired by TDK around May 18 (roughly the date your chart stops) so that's probably why there's no current price. Doesn't explain analysis reports, unless they just make them up at random :-)

Comment: @TripeHound Well, it's not "random" but I believe it is auto-generated.  Spot-checking the "analyst reports", they appear to be just regurgitating events from before the acquisition.  Unfortunately most of Google's "news" feed these says seems to be auto-generated click-bait.

Comment: @DStanley _auto-generated click-bait_ Why doesn't that surprise me?

Comment: Someone put up an answer so I Can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InvenSense Inc (NYSE:INVN) was taken over by TDK after they offered US$13.00 per share as a takeover offer.  TDK is based in Japan (TSE:6762, OTC:TTDKY, OTC:TTDKF).

InvenSense designs and produces sensor components for mobile devices.

Once stocks are delisted and no longer tradeable, most financial portal web sites remove all traces of their previous existence.